# How can I define an attribute as a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to define the following line as a variable in Jquery by using

```
var attributeID = $("#element_to_pop_up").attr("attrId");
```

The link I am using is and attrId is a variable

```
<a id="element_to_pop_up" attrId="variable">Link</a>
```

Basically, I am trying to define the value of my attribute "attrId" as a variable.

One more thing to note This is within a FreeMarker template so FreeMarker is already giving me my variable value. I don't have to do an `onclick` to get the value.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: well, it's one line- and quite straight forward. Looks fine to me

Comment: what exacly do yo try to get ? the above will give you attributeId==="variable"

Comment: shouldn't you only pull the attr onClick?

Comment: is `attrId` a valid attribute??

Comment: Well I just put "variable" there actually the attrId is dynamic and could be anything. I would just like to define the attribute value as a variable

Comment: Not trying to mock your English here, but your question isn't clear. Do you want to store the attribute value in a variable or do you want to store the variable in the attribute?

Comment: @Jacque Goupil my apologies for not being clear. Yes, I would like to store the attribute value in a variable

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 supports the notion of [*data attributes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for application-specific uses.  So a better approach is to name all your attributes with the `data-` prefix:

```
<a id="element_to_pop_up" data-attrid="variable">Link</a>
```

To include the information that @chris97ong added, the way to access this variable data using jQuery is:

```
var x= $('#element_to_pop_up').data('attrid');
```

Comment: @chris97ong please add your comment as a comment, not by editing my answer.

Comment: Well, his edit improved the answer, although it's a bit harsh not to mention an edit and pretend it was the original author's work.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil - I did mention his username in my answer.  You should not edit questions or answers to make a comment.  Sorry if it seems heavy-handed.  I'm not trying to pass it off as my information.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean that, haha. I meant that HE edited it without mentioning it was an edit. But I understand your point.